# Issue running IdentityServer4

Tags: asp.net, identityserver4

I am learning about the IdentityServer4 https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/release/quickstarts/0_overview.html but seem to be having issues getting it working.

After creating the API section of the project and configured accordingly:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        {
            loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
            loggerFactory.AddDebug();

            app.UseIdentityServerAuthentication(new IdentityServerAuthenticationOptions
            {
                Authority = "http://localhost:5000",
                RequireHttpsMetadata = false,

                ApiName = "api1"
            });

            app.UseMvc();
        }
```

I get the following error:

```
'IApplicationBuilder' does not contain a definition for 'UseIdentityServerAuthentication' and no extension method 'UseIdentityServerAuthentication' accepting a first argument of type 'IApplicationBuilder' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Any advice what i am missing here?

EDIT 1:
I've noticed i cannot reference the namespace either even tho the package is installed and present.

i.e.

```
using IdentityServer4.AccessTokenValidation;
```

or

```
using IdentityServer4;
```

Comment: Which version of Visual Studio are you using?  I am using VS 2017.  I had the same issue.  However, it would build even though it was showing this issue.  I closed and opened VS 2017 as @Jeremy Cook suggested and the issue went away.

Comment: Vs2017. Had same issue in vs2015. Restarting ide didn't help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to provide update/answer, the subsequent version of IdentityServer4 packages worked fine.

Currently using ID4 2.0 packages.

Comment: not really, I am on the latest release 2.0.6 and facing the same error!

Comment: correction, I am on ValidationToken package 2.2 and still have the same problem. Restarting VS doesn't work either...

Answer (score 23):

Well, I just closed and reopened Visual Studio 2017, and the problem went away. Perhaps Visual Studio choked on pulling down the IdentityServer4.AccessTokenValidation package the first time, and reopening the project caused it to try again and this time it succeeded.

Comment: Is this an suppose to be an answer or a comment?

Comment: @johnny5 It's an answer. I almost included in the answer "Yeah I know, lamest answer ever!" More importantly, it seems this issue isn't specific to that package and is a tooling issue that will hopefully go away after some VS updates, for example http://ardalis.com/force-nuget-to-reinstall-packages-without-updating

Comment: I got so confused I though you we're the OP for a bit because of the wording

Comment: Same here, closing the IDE and reopen it ! .

Comment: IdentityServer4.AccessTokenValidation 1.1.0 with asp.net core 1.1. close and re-open to make it work

Comment: doesn't work for me. On Vs2017 and AccessTokenValidation 2.2

Answer (score 23):

If you migrate from net core 1.1 to 2.0, you need to migrate your code as described in [Identity Server: API Migration to ASP.NET Core 2](https://elanderson.net/2017/09/identity-server-api-migration-to-asp-net-core-2/)

In the  Configure function

```
Before:
app.UseIdentityServerAuthentication(new IdentityServerAuthenticationOptions
{
    Authority = "http://localhost:5000",
    RequireHttpsMetadata = false,
    ApiName = "apiApp"
});

After:
app.UseAuthentication();
```

In the ConfigureServices function

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = 
                               JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = 
                               JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
}).AddJwtBearer(o =>
{
    o.Authority = "http://localhost:5000";
    o.Audience = "apiApp";
    o.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
});
```

Answer (score 14):

You need [this](https://www.nuget.org/packages/IdentityServer4.AccessTokenValidation/) package. And use the namespace `IdentityServer4.AccessTokenValidation`

Comment: Had that installed already, but interesting discovery, i tried referencing the namespace and its not being picked up.

Comment: @Aeseir I hit this same error yesterday while going through the tutorial. I'm in VS 2017 and `<TargetFramework>net461</TargetFramework>`. Not sure if that is related. I can see that that the package is included in .csproj as `<PackageReference Include="IdentityServer4.AccessTokenValidation" Version="1.1.0" />`

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue and I solved by following [IdentityServer 4 Quickstart Samples](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Samples/tree/release/Quickstarts), in particular the [Javascript Client](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Samples/tree/release/Quickstarts/7_JavaScriptClient) sample.

So, this is what it worked here:

1. Check dependencies versions. There are issues reported for IdentityServer running with [.NET Core 2.0](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/issues/1173). In my API project I used *Microsoft.Asp.NetCore.All* version 2.0.5 and *IdentityServer4.AccessTokenValidation* version 2.3.0.
2. Inside Startup.cs, at Configure method add: app.UseAuthentication(); as it is used in the [example](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Samples/blob/release/Quickstarts/7_JavaScriptClient/src/Api/Startup.cs#L42).
3. The last step is to add authentication to ConfigureServices method as it is in the [example](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Samples/blob/release/Quickstarts/7_JavaScriptClient/src/Api/Startup.cs#L17-L24):

   ```
   public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
   {
     services.AddMvcCore()
       .AddAuthorization()
       .AddJsonFormatters();

     services.AddAuthentication("Bearer")
       .AddIdentityServerAuthentication(options =>
       {
           options.Authority = "http://localhost:5000";
           options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;

           options.ApiName = "api1";
       });
    }
   ```

And that solved in my case. Hopefully it works for you too, just let me know how it goes.

Happy coding.

Comment: Thank you so much, you saved me a lot of time :)

Comment: Wunderbar !   This also works with .Net Core 2.1, unlike the other suggestions on this page.

Answer (score -1):

You can check the latest documentation at github [IdentityServer4](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.AccessTokenValidation):

It sets the authentication options in the `ConfigureServices` method using the `services.AddAuthentication` method.

Here is the [test server](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.AccessTokenValidation/blob/a190a380c90f223ba66983207be6f40003682862/test/Tests/PipelineFactory.cs#L19) code they are using